# Play video inside the tableviewcell using avplayer

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, avplayer

I am playing a video inside a table view cell with the following code ...

This is my `PlayerView` Class used in `UITableViewCell`

```
class PlayerView: UIView {
    var player: AVPlayer? {
        get {
            return playerLayer.player
        }
        set {
            playerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
            playerLayer.player = newValue
        }
    }

    var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer {
        return layer as! AVPlayerLayer
    }

    override static var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return AVPlayerLayer.self
    }
}
```

In `TableView` `cellForRowAt` there is a lot of different kind of cells ... but following is for video only ...

```
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "VideoCell") as! VideoThumbCell
                
         let url = URL(string:  message.Attachment?.URL ?? "")
         let avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: url!)
                
         cell.videoView.playerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
         cell.videoView.playerLayer.player = avPlayer
         cell.videoView.player?.isMuted = true         
              
         return cell
```

I play the video when `willDisplay` method get called ...

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let videoCell = cell as? VideoCell else { return }
        videoCell.videoView.player?.play()
    }
```

and stop when `didEndDisplaying` cell got called

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let videoCell = cell as? VideoCell else { return }
        
        videoCell.videoView.player?.pause()
        videoCell.videoView.player = nil
    }
```

This issue now I am facing is when the user scroll table view the cell got recreated because of `dequeueReusableCell` and I lost the state of the video ... when the user scrolls back to the same video it shows an empty view for some seconds... and then again play video from the beginning...

I try to prevent the video cell to be reused with `let cell = VideoCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.default,reuseIdentifier: "VideoCell")` ... but this doesn't work...

How to stop reloading video every single time when cell reappears just like other social media apps like Facebook...